# Read Status code

Tags: java, android

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) connectURL.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.connect();
int code = conn.getResponseCode();
```

I have successfully established a connection. I am trying to pass the information over the internet.When the url is opened via browser I am getting response as

```
{"status":"0","responseCode":"1001","response":"Wrong Settings."}
```

For correct status is returned as 1.

Is there any method where I can get the status only.I have been trying the following methods but every time I am getting code (below is code snippet) as -1 irrespect of status code when I am verifying manually via browser

Comment: I can see any setRequestProperty in your conn .So type of your ReuestProperty.I think it will be Json.

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON text. You will need to use a JSON library.

Comment: Hey mate can you help me with it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int code = conn.getResponseCode();
```

this method returns http status code, for http status codes see

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

while the response code you want to retrieve is actually the response string returned by the server.
To read this use:

```
 try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

     readStream(in);//method to read characters from stream.
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code for get Response string from your connection.

```
  OutputStream connectionOutput = null;
connectionOutput=connection.getOutputStream();
            connectionOutput.write(requestJson.toString().getBytes());
            connectionOutput.flush();
            connectionOutput.close();

            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

            ByteArrayOutputStream dataCache = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            // Fully read data
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buff)) >= 0) {
                dataCache.write(buff, 0, len);
            }

            // Close streams
            dataCache.close();
```

Now get Response string of json like below.

```
String jsonString = new String(dataCache.toByteArray()).trim();
JSONObject mJsonobject=new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

You can now parse your key from this `mJsonobject` Object.

Comment: Here connection will be your conn.

Comment: hey mate error at 
connectionOutput.write(requestJson.toString().getBytes());

Comment: requestJson is my json String  data that i am post to Server .So what you are sending to server that you have to write.

Comment: its working but I am getting an exception "java.net.ProtocolException: Does not support output"

Comment: And why you don't have this line `connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");` ,in Your code.